# Cursor.getString Returns Unexpected Output

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

I had tried Like this

```
curcountdueamount = mCon.DataFetch("select  sum(balance) as totalamount  from duebills");

while (curcountdueamount.moveToNext()) {

String xCountDueAmount = curcountdueamount.getString(curcountdueamount
                    .getColumnIndex("totalamount"));

}
```

Total amount Returns From Query as 6268064.695

But xCountDueAmount Returns as =6.26806e+06

when the total amount is less it returns correct when it exceeds some range it returns a decimal value .

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the value as a Long type.

```
Long x = curcountdueamount.getLong(curcountdueamount
                    .getColumnIndex("totalamount"));
```

Comment: Thanks  I got a solution

Answer (score 1):

The `e+06` is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and means 10 to the power of 6.

The value in the column is floating point and converting it to a string uses scientific notation by default for small and large values.

To control the formatting yourself, use `getDouble()` to get the floating point value yourself, and use e.g. [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to convert it to a string.